# Does ReactJS Component reload on History Forward?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ran into an interesting issue setting up routes in my app.  I have a component that requests an html stream from the server when the component is loaded based on a props.doctype variable:

```
import {ajaxCall} from '../global';
import React,{Component} from "react";
import Panel from '../comp/panel/panel';

import "./login.css";

    class Legal extends Component{
      constructor(props,context){
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {data: ""}
      };
      componentDidMount(){
        let opts = {"type":this.props.doctype};
        ajaxCall("http://localhost:5000/legal",opts,this.handleResponse.bind(this))
      };
      handleResponse(resp){
        console.log(this.state)
        let data = resp.data;
        this.setState({data:data});
      };
      render(){
        return(
          <div className="legal" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}}></div>
      )};
    }
    export default Legal
```

The Route to this component looks like this:

```
<Route path="/Login/Terms" render={(props)=><Legal doctype="terms"/>} />
```

and the Link:

```
<NavLink to={pathname:"/Login/Terms",doctype:"terms"}}>Terms</NavLink>
```

The problem I am running into is when the `Legal` component loads, it correctly loads the associated html from the server; however, if I hit the back button on the browser and then the forward button, I get a blank page with no errors.  Is there an issue with the way I am routing?

***Edit ***
Login Component:

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import LoginForm from "./loginform";
import Legal from "./legal";

const Login = (props) =>{
  return(
    <Router>
        <div className="content">
          <Route exact path="/Login" component={LoginForm} />
          <Route path="/Login/Terms" render={(props)=><Legal doctype="terms"/>} />
          <Route path="/Login/Privacy" component={Legal} />
          <Route path="/Login/Recoverpw" component={Recover} />
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
<NavLink to={pathname:"/Login/Terms",doctype:"terms"}}>Terms</NavLink>
```

When you are routing like this you have `doctype` props in the Legal component but when you direclty load the component from url like `http://localhost:3000/Login/Terms`, the component no longer has the `doctype` prop, so it can't fetch the HTML content appropriately and renders a white screen.

Comment: I see that as the problem as well.  Any odea on how to fix it?

Comment: You can set a default prop for the component to be present when the props from parent component is not defined.

Comment: You can also check the window.location.pathname and set the component doctype based on it.

Comment: So if a user hits the forward button, where would I check for the pathname?  `compnentDidMount()` is not called on a forward button click.

Comment: `compnentDidMount()` is called everytime your component mounts and renders for the first time.when you hit the back button, for sure the component should be unmounted and by clicking the fw button it mounts again. If it's not so, you can check it in `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: Unfotunately, clicking the forward button does not remount the component.  Theis is where I am running into trouble as I have to load data from a server everytime that page is displayed.  I put together a sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-hill-ffoq9
Open your console, follow the links.